# Muscles-strenght-height by avoiding ldl cholesterol

Tags: muscle-gain

First,why is bad ldl cholesterol is affecting bad the muscle growth ? The truth is I want to obtain muscle but with no eating it can't be obtained ,I don't want to have muscle with ldl cholesterol.About me ,I can eat everything .I eat healthy vegetables,protein, fruits and right foods.As far as I read is bad.My questions  are is doing bad in my muscles growth( on entire body) the ldl cholesterol? Strength ,if there is ldl cholysterol influence the blood so influence and the strength we gain when we workout?I mean if i have high level ldl that will be doing me not to obtain strength as i would gain if my cholyaterol ldl was low.Additional,ldl affecting height gain?The bones?etc? example ,milk is have a lot of calcium needed for height but it has a lot cholesterol, so milk isn't helpful for gain height,right?Cholesterol ldl is doing bad in blood so no much muscle gain ,no much strength gain ,no much height gain as a result doing bad in whole body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the notion that LDL cholesterol is bad per se is a bit oversimplified. Yes, it's called the "bad cholesterol" for a reason but context matters. In presence of enough HDL, good triglyceride values etc., higher than average LDL isn't much of a problem. It's not enough just to look at LDL cholesterol.

It's also important to understand that eating cholesterol does not necessarily result in high cholesterol in your blood. This notion is also oversimplified. Your body makes its own cholesterol and it's very important because your body makes hormones (such as testosterone, very important for muscle growth) or Vitamin D from it. Caution: More cholesterol does not mean more testosterone.

As far as I know cholesterol does not directly influence muscle growth. If your doctor says your blood values are OK, don't think about cholesterol too much. This is not the reason you are not gaining muscle. The master levers for muscle growth are: heavy exercise, a high protein intake, eating enough (more than needed) calories and adequate levels of testosterone.

Most people who have trouble gaining muscle undereat or don't eat enough protein. Most of the time it's both because if you eat enough on a regular diet, you also get enough protein.

No food will you help you become taller.